# Unexpected result when creating pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas

Been a while since using pandas package and I am getting unexpected results when creating a pandas Series from dict.    Simplified data attached:

```
d = {numpy.datetime64('2015-01-07T02:00:00.000000000+0200'): 42544017.198965244,
 numpy.datetime64('2015-01-08T02:00:00.000000000+0200'): 40512335.181958228,
 numpy.datetime64('2015-01-09T02:00:00.000000000+0200'): 39712952.781494237,
 numpy.datetime64('2015-01-12T02:00:00.000000000+0200'): 39002721.453793451}
s = pd.Series(d)
s
```

this gives me:

```
2015-01-07   NaN
2015-01-08   NaN
2015-01-09   NaN
2015-01-12   NaN
dtype: float64
```

This is totally unexpected to me as I am quite sure that Series creates a sorted by key Series when a dict is passed.   Will still check if this is different in prior versions of pandas.   I am using 0.15.2 here.    Any suggestions?

Just tested on pandas 0.10.0 and get the same results.   Am I missing something or is it something to do with the types that I am passing?

Further testing reveals that it is the datetime that is causing the problems.  They originate from pandas read_csv method with parse_dates applied.   Weird that it should be a problem.   Suspect it might be pandas bug?

As requested by Jeff here is code that generated the dict from pandas dataframe:

```
def _calculate_notional_cash(self):
    '''Calculate the notional cash in portfolio
    Done by getting difference beteen NAV and sum of positions
    self.PMSposition_dict is dict of dataframes with Position information
    '''
    sumpos={}
    for FundID, FundName in self.fund_number_name.iteritems():
        sumpos[FundID] = {}
        # self.PMSposition_dict[FundID]['MarketValueInZAR'].sum()
        for date in self.PMSposition_dict[FundID].Date.unique():
            s = self.PMSposition_dict[FundID][self.PMSposition_dict[FundID]['Date'] == date]['MarketValueInZAR'].sum()
            sumpos[FundID][date] = s
    self.sumpos = sumpos
```

Comment: I'll mark this as a bug, see here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9456 (and same soln as given below). I generally don't advise working directly with np.datetime64's like this in any event.

Comment: as mentioned i did not genererate the datetimes.   they got in that format by using pandas reead_csv parse dates method.    Any suggestions on how i can fix this at reading csv file point.   using... pd.read_csv(latest, parse_dates=[0], sep='\t')

Comment: if you used read_csv why would you have a dict? it returns an already parsed DataFrame. pls show complete code

Comment: had some complex filtering that could probably have been done in pandas, but was easier to iterate over Dataframe and get the values like that.   I know speed, but was opting for programming speed as opposed to program speed. will show code that got me dict from dataframe

Comment: added the method that generates the dict...

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this problem :

```
pd.Series(index=d.keys(), data=d.values())
```